# How to change the default output format for boolean values

Tags: postgresql

In a Postgres database, I know how to use case statements to get only TRUE or FALSE for a boolean field but was wondering whether there is a cleaner way to set this up like changing any configuration in the db.

Update: in Postgres, a the boolean representation for true is not only TRUE but also: yes, y, on, "t". So, I am inserting values with value TRUE. However, the SELECT command returns those values as "t".

Comment: Can you give an example of a value that you are trying to prevent? Post create table statement

Comment: Are you looking for a boolean expression (rather than a CASE _expression_)? e.g. `value > 42`

Comment: Could you provide more detail about what you mean by "set this up?"

Comment: Show an example of a CASE statement that is not clean enough for you.

Comment: @Lennart I created my table using "CREATE TABLE T ( b boolean not null default FALSE );". Inserted a TRUE value but the Select command returns "t". So, when I send this to Angular app, it expects to receive a boolean value, not a string.

Comment: @CL Well, I am in the situation where I need to pull 14 fields from a table with 5 boolean fields. It would very easy to do: SELECT table.*...... But using Case Statements, I need to call 11 fields directly (table.name, table.price, table.id, table.category...) plus create 5 case statements. This is not a clean query. It could be simplified if I am could set my database to returns only true when it is a true value instead of a "t".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the root of this issue. Postgres is fine. It returns boolean as true and numbers as int except decimal type values.

The problem was I was using pg_connect in PHP and fetchAll of this library casts everything to string. I am using PDO now and everything is normal.

Lets close this thread.

Comment: To "close" this question, you need to accept an answer. It's perfectly fine to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something that I don't understand about your question but given a table with a boolean attribute like:

```
create table T ( b boolean not null );
```

You can only insert True, False. Under what circumstances would you need a CASE expression?

Edit:

reading your comments above, I guess you are interested in a textual representation of t/f. Not sure if it fits your needs but you can cast it to text:

```
select b::text from T
```

If you want it to be TRUE/FALSE I guess you will have to:

```
select upper(b::text) from T
```

Perhaps a function would be cleaner?

```
CREATE FUNCTION showbool(boolean) RETURNS text
    AS $$ SELECT UPPER(CAST($1 AS text)) $$
    LANGUAGE SQL;

select showbool(b) from T
```

Comment: Boolean in postgres is much more than only true and false. You can use": True False, true, false, ‘t’, ‘f‘, ‘true’, ‘false’, 'y’, ‘n’, ‘yes’, ‘no’, ‘1’, ‘0’, on, off.

Comment: I would say that 'no' etc are casted to boolean

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you .. use this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/ddl-default.html

```
CREATE TABLE T (
b boolean not null default FALSE
);
```

on the other hand postgres still allows for more values that will be translated to true or false (Table of literal values for true and false according to http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-boolean/)

```
True   False
true   false
‘t’    ‘f‘
‘true’ ‘false’
‘y’    ‘n’
‘yes’  ‘no’
‘1’    ‘0’
```

so you probably can't enforce true / false - on other hand a select will deliver true / false as you want

Comment: I have updated my question but yes, that's what I want to avoid. If I insert TRUE, I don't expect to get "t".

Comment: The `t` output completely depends on the SQL client you are using

Comment: @eagle275 I created my table using the same command you posted. Inserted a TRUE value but the Select command returns "t". So, when I send this to Angular app, it expects to receive a boolean value, not a string.

Comment: @LuisArriojas: Postgres **does** return real boolean value. The `t` you are seeing is just the default output format applied by e.g. `psql`. If you retrieve the value (correctly) in a programming language, you **will** get a proper boolean value. Don't confuse output formatting with the actual column value

Comment: That's what I accounted for - given its some years back that I supported a team mate with postgre but I remember that the boolean coliumn  beautifully corresponded to a boolean value in my chosen programming language (JAVA at that time) - but Angular as a webservice might blur the lines